# Interval of convergence of the infinite series $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I am self-learning real-analysis from the text, *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott. I'd like for someone to verify, if my deduction below is rigorous and correct.

> **[Abbott 6.4.4]** Define:

$$g( x) =\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$$

Find the values of $\displaystyle x$ where the series converges and show that we get a continuous function on this set.

***Proof***.

Let $\displaystyle x$ belong to any compact interval $\displaystyle [ a,b]$ such that $\displaystyle -1< a< b< 1$. Let $\displaystyle c=\max\{|a|,|b|\}$.

We have:

$$g_{n}( x) =\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} \leq x^{2n} \leq c^{2n}$$

Define $M_{n} =c^{2n}$. Then,

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} M_n =\frac{1}{1-c^{2}}$$

By the Weierstrass $\displaystyle M$-test, the infinite series $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ converges uniformly on $\displaystyle [a,b]$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_{n}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to $\displaystyle g$, and each $\displaystyle g_{n}$ is continuous on $\displaystyle [ a,b]$, by the term-by-term continuity theorem, $\displaystyle g$ is continuous on $\displaystyle [a,b]$.

Also, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2n}$ converges pointwise on $(-1,1)$. So, by the comparison test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ converges pointwise on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: You still need to argue that radius of convergence is not greater than $1$.

Comment: On the "rigorous" front, you need to bound the absolute value of $g_n(x)$. You did all the preparation work, e.g. when defining $c$, but forgot it in the inequality. It's a trivial step in such proofs often, but if the term is more complicated (like  a sum), forgetting it can introduce "real" errors. Like in this case, if $x<0$, the denominator is less than $1$, so your inequality does not hold then (it can be repaired though).

Comment: Yes! Luckily, in this textbook example, $|g_n(x)|=g_n(x)$, since both the numerator and denominator are non-negative.

Comment: Ops, sorry. Since each exponent is $2n$, nothing becomes negative/less than $1$. But it will be relevant if you replace $2n$ with $n$ in the formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of the convergence might be greater than 1.

proposing another way that you can do it:

Definition:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{1 + x^{2n}}$$

#case 1: $\lvert x \rvert > 1 \to \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x^{2n}=\infty$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{1 + x^{2n}} = 1$$

#case 2: $\lvert x \rvert =1$
$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{1 + x^{2n}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Then, for $\lvert x \rvert \ge 1$, $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{1 + x^{2n}}$  does not converge, and for $\lvert x \rvert < 1$:
$$\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{1 + x^{2n}} \leq \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} x^{2n}$$

And since $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} (x^2)^n$ is a geometric sequence with $x^2 < 1$, it converges, thous, $f(x)$ also converges. $\square$